# Display image that are stored in public folder in Laravel 8

Tags: php, laravel, image, store

Hello I already stored my images in the public folder but it doesn't display anything ! Someone to help me please ?
(PS: I add image with a form the input file)
Blade File:

```
@forelse ($data as $key)
            <tr>
                <th scope="row">{{ $loop->index + 1 }}</th>
                <td>{{ $key->title }}</td>
                <td><image style="width:70px;" src="{{ asset('public/Image/'.$key->image) }}"/></td>
                    <td></td>
            </tr>
        @empty
            <tr>
                <td colspan="4" class="text-center">No post found.</td>
            </tr>
        @endforelse
```

Controller File store function:

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $post = new Post;
    $this->validate($request, [
        'title' => 'required',
        'image' => 'required',
        'description' => 'required',
        'price' => 'required',
        'category' => 'required',
        'location' => 'required',
        'state' => 'required',
        'image.*' => 'image|mimes:jpeg,png,jpg,gif,svg|max:2048'
    ]);

    if($request->hasFile('image'))
    {

        $file= $request->file('image');
        $extension= $file->getClientOriginalExtension();
        $filename = time().'.'.$extension;
        $file-> move('public/Image/', $filename);
        $post->image = $filename;

    }
     
    $input = $request->except(['_token']);
    $input = $request->all();
    $input['category'] = $request->input('category');
    $input = $request->all();
    $input['state'] = $request->input('state');
    Post::create($input);

    return redirect()->route('posts.index')
        ->with('success','Post created successfully.');


        
}
```

[My images are stocked here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ogbhr.png)

Comment: `asset()` should already be looking in the public folder and is generating a browser-usable path. You can drop that part of the path.

Comment: I did it but it doesn't display anything

Comment: Look at the source in the browser, and check the path to the image. What does it say?

Comment: Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)

Comment: What is it showing for the path? Not the status.

Comment: phpDF83.tmp:1  this...

Comment: http://127.0.0.1:8000/public/Image/C:/xampp/tmp/php8EB9.tmp

Comment: You're saving the wrong link to the file in your Post. `Post::create($input);` ignores everything you've done with the file movement and post creation/updates, and saves just what is in your request.

Comment: So I have to delete it ?

Comment: In your original code, you have `$post->image = $filename;`, but you're not saving `$post.` Instead, you're using `Post::create($input);` but the new filename is not being stored in the input. My code moved the input above the file movement, so that you can modify the image property of `$input`. And also removed the extra bits of code you didn't need, such as creating `$input` 3 different times.

Comment: So I have to change that ```$input['image'] = $filename;``` and replace $filename with $post->image ?

Comment: First part, yes. Second part, no, since you're not doing anything with `$post`, you don't need to create or update that at all

Comment: So what I have to write instead ? I'm verry confused sorry...

Comment: See my answer, if that doesn't work, let me know exactly what isn't working.

Comment: I tried it but same errors I don't know what's going on with my code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're currently saving the temporary location of the file upload coming from your input into the new post. You need to rearrange your function a bit to grab the input, then save the filename into the input before you create the post.

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $this->validate($request, [
        'title' => 'required',
        'image' => 'required',
        'description' => 'required',
        'price' => 'required',
        'category' => 'required',
        'location' => 'required',
        'state' => 'required',
        'image.*' => 'image|mimes:jpeg,png,jpg,gif,svg|max:2048'
    ]);
    
    $input = $request->except(['_token']);

    if($request->hasFile('image'))
    {

        $file= $request->file('image');
        $extension= $file->getClientOriginalExtension();
        $filename = time().'.'.$extension;
        $file-> move('public/Image/', $filename);
        $input['image'] = $filename; // Save the new and correct file name into the input

    }

    Post::create($input);

    return redirect()->route('posts.index')
        ->with('success','Post created successfully.');

}
```

Comment: Just tried it it doesn't work...

Comment: Now what is being stored in the filename?

Comment: Please could you explain me more clearly what do you mean by that where do I have to change the filename I didnt really understand ?

Answer (score -1):

Try this one

```
<image style="width:70px;" src="{{url('public/Image/'.$key->image')}}"/>
```